# View with UITableVIew and some buttons as tabs below in a Tabbar App possible?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, overriding

How can I make an iphone application that uses a UITableView but so the it won't ocupy all the screen?
I want to put below some buttons that will have the role of tabs so when i press one, a different UIView(UiTableVIew) will show above.
I know I have to extend somehow the class and modify it's apearance but it can't find an example so that the table is not the main view
I have something like this

```
View 
 -TableView
 -UIImage (as background)
 -button1
 -button2
 -button3
 -button4
 -button5 (will use this as a badge)
```

here's an example
[screen shot for the layout](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_xe9TQhB7n2Q/TW9i528PqzI/AAAAAAAAB7I/LRg7xZBv5Ew/Untitled-1.jpg)

I know it's not very standard, usualy you do this with the upper part bar..
but it's the way I have to make it so it has been chosen...

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy:
1) don' use a UITableViewController, use a subclass of UIViewController
2) in your xib file (or your code), set the frame of the UITableView however you like
3) don't forget to have your UIViewController class confom to UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols, and to set your UIViewController as the delegate of the UITableView object.

Comment: will this do? @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>  { }
then put the events on the implementation (i have copied it from the template of the UITableViewController)

Comment: still i don't get one thing in the interfacebuilder (see this: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_xe9TQhB7n2Q/TW-LK2NYspI/AAAAAAAAB7k/HRHcZn45KH8/s640/grab1.png)  i don't know what delegate referrers to ..datasource i know it's a table's part..so the app crashes...when i try to display that..if i quite the datasource and put the delegate to file's owner it works (file's owner is of type FirstViewController)

Comment: Yes, that's the last thing I wrote: you must set both your datasource and delegate outlets in the uitableview to be the file's owner